# Reference type inside class in javascript not working as expected

Tags: javascript, oop, types

```js
class Node {
  constructor(val) {
    this.val = val;
    this.next = null;
  }
}

class Stack {
  // construstor
  constructor() {
    this.first = null;
    this.last = null;
    this.size = 0;
  }

  // use push
  push(val) {
    // newNode
    let newNode = new Node(val)
    // If length is 0
    if (this.size == 0) this.first = this.last = newNode;
    // if not
    else {
      let current = this.first;
      // reset the first 
      this.first = newNode;

      console.log(">>><<<<<<<<<>>>>><", typeof current, current, this.first, typeof this.first)
    }
    this.size++;
  }
}

let s = new Stack;
s.push(1);
s.push(2);
```

I am writing code for stack implemention by looking into a tutorial.

I was confused at this step

```
console.log(">>><<<<<<<<<>>>>><",typeof current,current,this.first,typeof this.first)
```

I am getting typeof current as `object` according to my understanding object are **reference types** in my previous step I initialized

```
this.first = newNode;
```

As reference types this.first and current must be same but they are showing different values why (first has different value and current has different value)?

Answer (score 1):

They're showing different values because you're reassigning them to different values.

When you do

```
current = this.first;
```

they're references to the same object. But then you do

```
this.first = newNode;
```

Now they're not references to the same object any more. `current` contains a reference to the previous contents of `this.first`, while `this.first` now contains a reference to `newNode`.